# How much do we know about this "local" Hardy-Littlewood maximal function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The "local" Hardy-Littlewood maximal function is given by $$(M_\phi f)(x)= \sup_{0<\epsilon<1}|\phi_\epsilon \ast f|(x),$$ which is similar to the classical Hardy-Littlewood maximal function : $$(Mf)(x)= \sup_{\epsilon>0}|(\chi_B)_\epsilon \ast f|(x),$$
where $\phi\in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is some nonnegative, radial, radially decreasing Schwartz function and $\phi_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^{-n}\phi(x/\epsilon)$.

The word "local" means that the supremum is only taken on small $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. It seems that this maximal function should have better properties than the classical one. For example, it is well known that if $f\in L^1$, then $Mf\notin L^1$ in general. However, we can easily check that for some $f\in L^1$, we do have $M_\phi f\in L^1$(e.g. $f(x)=\phi(x)=e^{-|x|^2}$).  Are there any references(e.g. books, papers,...) on this "local" maximal function? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but since you only refer to the classical $M$, it's worth mentioning that $\sup_{\epsilon>0} |\phi_t * f(x)| \leq \|\phi\|_1Mf(x)$. I can't grasp how the supremum taken on small epsilon changes the facts, but maybe in the notes and further results of Chapter 2 of Duoandikoetxea's Fourier Analysis book you can find something useful.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Thanks. Something may be different if the supremum is only taken on small $\epsilon$. For example, if $f\in L^1$, one can show that $Mf(x)\ge C|x|^{-n}, |x|>>1$ by taking $\epsilon\approx |x|$, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252595/lower-bound-for-the-hardy-littlewood-maximal-function-implies-it-is-not-integrab?rq=1 But this inequality can not hold if  if the supremum is only taken on small $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure of the maximal function to be a bounded map in $L^1$ is not just an issue of "failure at infinity".

Consider the case of $n = 1$. Let $f$ be a non-negative function that is compactly supported, and smooth away from the origin. Near the origin suppose that 
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{|x| (\ln |x|)^2} $$
This function can be easily checked to be in $L^1$, as we can integrate, for $y> 0$ close to zero, 
$$ \int_0^y f(x) ~\mathrm{d}x = - \frac{1}{\ln y} $$

If you apply your local maximal function to $f$ (with the positivity assumption, WLOG, that $\phi(y) \geq c > 0$ whenever $|y| \leq 1$), you have that for $y\in (0,\epsilon)$ that 
$$ M_\phi f(y) \gtrsim - \frac{1}{y \ln y} $$
which implies that $M_\phi f(y)$ is not integrable near the origin.

---

The local properties of the maximal function (the classical one, but it applies almost identically to your version with the Schwartz weight) is remarked upon in Section 5.2, Chapter 1 of Stein's *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*, where you can find the assertion 
$$ Mf [\log (2 + Mf)]^k \in L^1_{loc} \iff |f| [\log (2 + |f|)]^{k+1} \in L^1_{loc} $$
for any non-negative integer $k$.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful. BTW, since $\frac1{|x|(\ln |x|)^2}$ is not integrable near $x=1$, you may need to multiply it by a characteristic function, e.g. $f(x)=\frac{\chi_{(0,1/2)}}{|x|(\ln |x|)^2}$.

Comment: @Mr.right: I wrote "Let $f$ be a non-negative function that is compactly supported, and smooth away from the origin. Near the origin suppose..."

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. If $f\in L^1\cap L^\infty$, do we have $M_\phi f\in L^1$? (Clearly, $M_\phi f\in L^p,\ p>1$). More generally, how much do we know about $f$ when $M_\phi f\in L^1$?